# Is decompression possible with PCA?

Tags: pca

PCA can be used to compress data by reducing the vectors containing the least amount of information based on the eigen vectors sorted according to the eigen Values.

Is it possible to reverse this process ?  What I mean by reversing the process is that we take the compressed data set and we must try to get an estimation of the original data set.

I'm trying to accomplish this within the scope of sound compression and decompression.
I have achieved decompression by using the original eigen vectors, this means the process is not applicable in real life.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why does using the original eigenvectors mean the process is not applicable in real life?

Comment: It's my understanding that if you compress the data, you will not store the eigenvectors of the original data. Also the eigenvectors we get of the compressed data are different than the original ones. I may be mistaken.
So if you compress an image for example the original eigenvectors are discarded

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. One example is reconstructing an image from its compressed representation:

1. take the original image
2. apply PCA on the original image
3. decide of much variance you want to retain and from that build your compressed data
4. apply the inverse PCA transformation from point 2. on the compressed data to get the reconstructed image

In point 3. the higher the variance you pick the more similar to the original/higher quality your final reconstructed image will be, but of course also less compressed. On the other hand picking smaller variance leads to better compression but lower final quality.

Check out [this notebook](https://github.com/mGalarnyk/Python_Tutorials/blob/master/Sklearn/PCA/PCA_Image_Reconstruction_and_such.ipynb) for one of the many examples you can find over the internet.

Comment: Good answer. To expand on this, PCA is just a linear transformation from one coordinate system to another, which can easily be "undone" in a lossless manner by reversing the transformation. The dimensionality reduction aspect comes when you start dropping the last principal components, which are the dimensions which capture the least variance. Without those, you can't perfectly reverse the transformation, but your reconstruction will be better if the PCs you keep collectively capture most of the variance in the data.

Comment: your first 3 steps are understood and I've managed to implement this in matlab. I have trouble understanding the 4th step though. Getting eigenvectors of the compressed data and inversing it, then projecting in then reconstructing the compressed data can't mathematically decompress the data to its state in 1

Comment: Thanks for the notebook link by the way, it's really well done.  
I'm trying to understand the In[65] : pcs.inverse_transform part

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. As Nuclear Wang wrote PCA is a transformation from one space to another say from X to Z. Mathematically this is represented by a matrix and this can be inverted (you can use the transpose, but watch out for mean and scaling) to perform the opposite, from Z to X. In point 3 you decide whether (and how much) to compress the data. If you compress you can't go back to its original state in 1, you are removing part of the signal, so when you convert it back to the original space you don't have all information necessary to reconstruct the original signal in point 1.

Answer (score 1):

Following the notation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Dimensionality_reduction), the $L$ dimensional PCA compression is performed as following:

$ T_L = X W_L $

where $W_L$ is a matrix whose columns are the $L$ eigenvectors with the highest eigenvalues of the matrix $X^TX$.

In order to reverse this compression you can right multiply both sides of the equation by of $W_L^T$, giving:

$T_L W_L^T \approx X $

You can see this implemented in sklearn in the implementation of [inverse_transform](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/decomposition/_base.py#L135).

I can only give a hand-wavy version of the math, essentially because $X^T X$ is symmetric and positive definite we have that the eigenvectors of $X^T X$ are orthogonal (and can be made to have unit norm). Thus $W$ is orthonormal and $W^{-1} = W^T$.

So yes, in order to "decompress" you need to store $W_L$, the matrix containing the eigenvectors derived from the original dataset.